# Help identify this tree

Tags: identification, trees

Hello botanists and the like,

I was hoping for some assistance identifying a quite striking tree. This particular one is in Commonwealth Park, Canberra, Australia - but it doesn't seem like a native. I'd love to plant a few (probably for my great-grandkids to enjoy) and it seems like it has some fairly unique features that should make it easy to ID for anyone in the know.

Thanks!

**Trunk and Branches**
[image]

**Leaves**
[image]

**Roots (?)**
[image]

Comment: Now I need the terminology proposal (now active in meta). In last figures you see roots, specialized for respiration. So I would expect that this tree lives in a watery environment, where normal roots are often under water. I doesn't remember the tree genera which such features, nor the specific name of such roots, to search with google.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a *bald cypress*, also known as *swamp cypress*, and also known as *Taxodium distichum*.

It is a magnificent tree, and one of rare deciduous conifers. If you plant this tree, you get some of the feeling of Mississippi river swamps.

Here is a picture that compares Taxodium distichum and Metasequoia glyphostroboides leaves: (you can use it for further confirmation):

[image]

The well known air roots, "cypress knees":

[image]

(*all photo credits: Oregon State University*)

City planners in my city wanted to build a street over the area with several bald cypresses, however they had to change the project, and the street went around the area!

Comment: That looks like the one! I even found a website with pictures of the trees near me(https://www.gardensonline.com.au/GardenShed/PlantFinder/Show_1407.aspx), so thanks very much. Now to see if I can track some down at a local nursery.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is either:

- Taxodium mucronatum or more commonly Mexican Bald Cypress or Mexican Swamp Cypress or Montezuma Bald Cypress; or
- Taxodium distichum or more commonly Bald Cypress.

There is a very similar tree in the Royal Botanic Gardens Sydney. Refer to this website for details... specifically the last two images:

http://www.plantplaces.com/perl/viewplantdetails.pl?filter=plant&plant_ID=5604&Region=&Region_Search=&fullname=Taxodium%20mucronatum%20%20Mexican%20Bald%20Cypress

[image: Taxodium mucronatum - image from plantplaces website]